# VSCode font became microscopic for File|Open popup after minor settings change; How to revert?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, configuration

VSCode has been working flawlessly for me for over a year.

Today I made a minor change to the settings. Via the settings panel (Ctl-,) I set the editor font to Consolas and the font size to 13. This worked just fine. The editor looks good.

An unfortunate side effect of this change is that the File|Open popup (Ctrl-O) is now so microscopically small that it's unusable. Reverting the font changes I made above is of no use. I'm now unable to use the File|Open popup without a physical magnifying glass.

Here's a screenshot. Notice how unusably tiny the File|Open popup's font is compared to everything else. Clearly I've screwed up my configuration somehow but not sure what to revert back. Any ideas?

NOTE: All "zoom" features are turned off. But even if I play with zoom, this only affects the editor text, not the File|Open popup.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the protocol is for answering one's own question but for anyone who runs into the same issue...

One thing I didn't mention in my original question because I didn't think it was relevant is that I'm using a 32-inch Apple Pro Display XDR (6016 x 3384) which is plugged into my 2019 MacBook Pro. The VSCode app is running in a Windows RDP session.

Turns out, when using RDP sessions over a high resolution display, some apps don't show system dialogs in the correct resolution. VSCode is apparently affected by this bug.

To fix the problem, you'll need to create a new shortcut to VSCode. Then, in the properties for that shortcut, on the Compatibility tab, you'll need to tweak the DPI settings as shown in this image. It solves the problem. As to why the problem only manifested after a year, and only after changing the size of the editor font, I have no idea.

[image]

Comment: "_Not sure what the protocol is for answering one's own question..._" - You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here.